# Отследить в функции @ORM\PostUpdate какое поле было изменено в entity Doctrine 2?

Tags: doctrine2, symfony2

Возможно ли как-нибудь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html#preupdate

скорее всего метод `getEntityChangeSet()` именно то, что вы ищете.

Comment: Мне необходимо отслеживать именно в PostUpdate, так как в preUpdate запрещено делать сохранение других объектов.